# Python: convert unicode to file pointer

Tags: python

I have a variable say f which is initialized to a unicode string

```
f= u"<open file 'C:\\IVR\\log\\IVR.log', mode 'r' at 0x02A8AB20>"
```

I want to convert this to a file pointer type. Is it possible? ie

```
f=<open file 'C:\\IVR\\log\\IVR.log', mode 'r' at 0x02A8AB20>
```

Comment: How did you get that first `f` variable?

Comment: From django views Am passing a file pointer f as a string to my jquery using simplejson.dumps. Then on an ajax request the jquery sends back the same f as an unicode string back to my views. Now I need to convert it back to file pointer.

Comment: That sounds like an invitation for attacks. Someone modifying your JSON could get the app to open any arbitrary file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `f` in your JSON, use `f.name` which will just be the name of the file. Then you can reopen it easily.

If you expect your program to still have the file open, you can create a dict with the name of the file as the key and the file object as the value. This would actually be safer since an attacker couldn't open arbitrary files.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert a string to a file file pointer object. The best you can do is parse out the filename and re-open the file.